# How to use same login for different projects?

Tags: symfony

Ther is a way to login in different symfony projects by using only one main User entity?

I'll try to explain my need.

I have:

- Project 1 on server A (Main Project where i have all my users registered)
- Project 2 in server B
- Project 3 in server C

Now i would need to login in all projects only by using the data saved on User Entity on project A.

Of course by having all User data available like it was on the same project of the Entity (#[CurrentUser], $this->getUser() and so on)

Is that possible?